# HTML number input field that also works on mobile device

Tags: html, angular, typescript

When I set my input field type="time" or type="date" on my webapp, if I view the app in mobile device, I get nice UI such as the following when clicked on it

[image: time screen shot].

However, when I set type="number", I was expecting a number pad to pop up. However, I get a keyboard instead. If I set it to type="tel", would it cause a problem or is there a better solution?

[image: number]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Number Input is another way to offer numbers for your users. The difference between the number input and the tel input is that also offers easy access to special characters and symbols. However, if you only need numbers entered, it’s best to stick with the tel input.

```
<label class="item item-input">
<span class="input-label">Number</span>
<input type="number">
</label>
```

The Tel Input is a very unknown and underused input type. It displays a full numeric keypad, which makes for a great user experience when all that is required from the user is numbers. Take advantage of this one!

```
<label class="item item-input">
<span class="input-label">Telephone</span>
 <input type="tel">
</label>
```

For more information, read this article: http://ionicframework.com/html5-input-types/#number

Comment: Do you know how I can find out which device or which firmware supports this "number" input that will give me a keypad

Comment: normally a library called modernizr lets you do that. you will have to read up on it on how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<input type="number" min="0" inputmode="numeric" pattern="[0-9]*" />
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to input a number then input type="number" is there. But if u dont want to see mobile keypad then u can make your own keypad like this:

```
<html>
<head><title></title></head>
<body>

<script> function $(id) { return document.getElementById(id); } </script>

<input id="num" type="text" readonly="true"/>
<input type="button" value="..." onclick="$('keypad').style.display='inline-block';"/>

<div id="keypad" style="display:none; background:#AAA; vertical-align:top;">
<input type="button" value="7" onclick="$('num').value+=7;"/>
<input type="button" value="8" onclick="$('num').value+=8;"/>
<input type="button" value="9" onclick="$('num').value+=9;"/><br/>
<input type="button" value="4" onclick="$('num').value+=4;"/>
<input type="button" value="5" onclick="$('num').value+=5;"/>
<input type="button" value="6" onclick="$('num').value+=6;"/><br/>
<input type="button" value="1" onclick="$('num').value+=1;"/>
<input type="button" value="2" onclick="$('num').value+=2;"/>
<input type="button" value="3" onclick="$('num').value+=3;"/><br/>
<input type="button" value="X" onclick="$('keypad').style.display='none'"/>
<input type="button" value="0" onclick="$('num').value+=0;"/>
<input type="button" value="&larr;" onclick="$('num').value=$('num').value.substr(0,$('num').value.length-1);"/>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This answer makes no sense at all.